# DirectoryStream return path in what kind of order? filename, last modified, filesize?

Tags: java, directorystream

I am trying to read multiple files in a folder using DirectoryStream. There are 10 items altogether.

> doc_01.txt, doc_02.txt, doc_03.txt, doc_04.txt, doc_05.txt, doc_06.txt, doc_07.txt, doc_08.txt, doc_09.txt, doc_10.txt

I wanted the file to be read in the order of their filename.
Does DirectoryStream read the file in order of their filename? Because this is the result I get:

> ./mydata/doc_01.txt, ./mydata/doc_02.txt, ./mydata/doc_03.txt, ./mydata/doc_04.txt, ./mydata/doc_08.txt, ./mydata/doc_07.txt, ./mydata/doc_09.txt, ./mydata/doc_10.txt, ./mydata/doc_05.txt, ./mydata/doc_06.txt

This is my code:

```
public static void readData(){
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Start reading");

    Path path = Paths.get(String.join(File.separator, ".", "mydata"));

    try(DirectoryStream<Path> stream = 
            Files.newDirectoryStream(path, "*.txt")
    ){
        for(Path entry : stream){
            System.out.println("reading: " +entry.toString());
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Instant end = Instant.now();
    System.out.println("Done in " + Duration.between(start, end).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The javadoc of class [DirectoryStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.html)
explicitly says:

> The elements returned by the iterator are **in no specific order**.
> Some file systems maintain special links to the directory itself
> and the directory's parent directory. Entries representing these links
> are not returned by the iterator.

So, if you need a specific order, it's up to you to sort the `Path`s.
For example, for an alphabetical sorting you can do like this:

```
DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = ...;
StreamSupport.stream(directoryStream.spliterator(), false)
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Path::toString))
    .forEach(p -> { System.out.println("reading: " + p); });
```

Comment: I guess i didnt read the API thoroughly. But this explains it then. thanks alot.   :)  This question can be closed now i supposed.

Comment: Thanks, solves my problem.. On Windows they are returned in order but on MacOS they are not, as I do my main testing on Windows I have only just picked up on this problem.